# How can I extend PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

The PHPUnit manual says this:

> "Write custom assertions and utility methods in an abstract subclass
>   of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase and derive your test case classes from
>   that class. This is one of the easiest ways to extend PHPUnit."

So I figure I will do something like this:

```
class MyTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

  // new methods go here

}
```

Then I will derive my own test cases from this class.  But the problem is where do I put this code?  I mean, into which file in my test directory?

If I put it in it's own file, or at the start of any particular test file, then, because I don't know the order that the tests will run, I can't be sure that the class definition will be included before it is needed.

You used to be able to define a bootstrap file which would run before any of the tests, for doing initial setup, but this feature has been removed from recent editions of PHPUnit.  The PHPUnit manual doesn't explain why, but it does say that sharing fixtures between tests is bad practice, so perhaps the feature was removed to stop the temptation to share fixtures.

The only thing I can think of at the moment is putting an include_once() at the top of all my test files - essentially recreating manually the deprecated bootstrap feature, but in a more error prone and tedious way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > You used to be able to define a bootstrap file which would run before any of the tests, for doing initial setup, but this feature has been removed from recent editions of PHPUnit.

This is wrong. I don't know where you got that from. The feature of the bootstrap file has NOT been removed, neither from the code nor from the documentation.

Comment: I got it from the manual:   http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html   The bootstrap line has been commented out.  I discovered this when I tried to use the bootstrap option and it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is valid proof of the removal. The listing this is contained in states that the XML attributes correspond to the command line options. And the `--bootstrap` command line has not been removed.

Comment: Additionally, the commented bootstrap attribute has been added to the 4.1 documentation on 2014-01-17, because the previous versions did contain it as well. The first version containing a commented bootstrap attribute is 3.5, originating from about 2011.

Comment: So: If it does not work, show us what you did in more detail. You did something wrong somewhere.